# Is it possible to change default row dragging preview and animation?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am wondering if I can customize row dragging animation. So far, I have been customizing CSS to make ag-grid fit my need but I cannot find how to change default row dragging by changing CSS only. From official documentation, the only thing about animation is written on this page [grid-animation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-animation/) and is about setting a property on the grid for activating the animation. Except that, it seems there is nothing related to customizing dragging animation.

Is there any way to change default animation and dragging preview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AgGrid custom html on drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367662/aggrid-custom-html-on-drag)

Comment: @un.spike thanks. I'll check it out. It seems like I cannot do this by modifying CSS only.